# Azure data sync client - How to sync 2 local databases to different azure accounts?

Tags: sql-server, azure, synchronization, client, azure-data-sync

This is my scenario:

One Windows Server with one SQL Server with two Databases (localDbA, localDbB).
Two Azure accounts/abonnements (Abo1 with cloudDb1, Abo2 with CloudDb2).

Now I need to sync localDbA to cloudDb1 and localDbB with cloudDb2.

But the data sync agent can only work with one submit key!
Is this feature not supported?

Answer (score 0):

you can only register a data sync agent against one Data Sync Service and you cannot install multiple instances of the Data Sync Agent on the same box either.

so it's either you install Data Sync Agents on two machines or you sync both on-premise databases on one of the subscription and have another sync group that syncs that hub from the previous sync group to the other SQL Azure DB on the other subscription.